# Prototype a function to another function JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I was asked the following question at an OA. I did not figure it out and I would like to know the solution to this question.

I was asked to console `Thank you for Logging in Dan`:

```
var Wrap = (function(){
  function User(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  var d = function(){
    console.log('1');
    return "Thank you for Logging in" + this.name;
  };
  User.prototype.thankForLoggingln = d;
  return User;
})();
```

I figured that out that `Wrap` returns User, which make `Wrap` equals to `User`. And if I do `Wrap('Dan')`, `this.name` will change to `Dan`.

The question is, I cannot access to `thankForLoggingln`. I have tried `Wrap.()thankForLoggingln()` and things like this, I got reference errors. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of

> I figured that out that Wrap returns User, which make Wrap equals to
>   User

is correct. But when you say `Wrap('Dan')`, in this case `this` would refer to the Global object. In case, you are running this on a browser, then you can access your name variable by `window.name`. You must call the function with the `new` keyword, so that a new object would be created and `this` would refer to the newly created object and `User` would be it's constructor. In this case it would have access to the `thankForLoggingln` function.

So the correct way of doing it would be

```
var user = new Wrap('Dan');
user.thankForLoggingln();
```

For more information read [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) and [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)

Answer (score 1):

```
User.prototype.thankForLoggingln = d;
```

means user objects created using User as a constructor inherit `thankForLogging in.

So

```
console.log( new Wrap(" Dan").thankForLoggingln());
```

does the trick. There should be a console.log of '1' immediately prreceeding it.

Two addditional traps were set:

- `thankForLogginln` end in lower case L fofollowed by 'n'. Spellng it as 'thankForLogginIn` takes debugging.
- The name has to be supplied with a leading space to print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of *User* by instantiating *Wrap* like so:

```
var user = new Wrap('Dan');
```

With that instance, you can then call the  *thankYouForLoggingIn* method like so:

```
var message = user.thankYouForLoggingIn();
console.log(message);
```

So your code example is really just a fancy way of creating a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try following will surely work.

```
Wrap.prototype.thankForLoggingln()
```

The function gets invoked immediately,after trying Wrap it gave me this output. So the

> ```
> ƒ User(name){
>     this.name = name;
>   }
> ```

Basically it followed the clean inheritance using prototype.So Wrap.prototype gives both method as well as constructor user.Either access using new keyword or using prototype.
Check following:

[About Prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)